# Facebook YouTube Embed og:meta Tags Suddenly Quit Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, youtube, youtube-api

[FYI: There is another question with a similar title posted on stack overflow but the questions are completely different]

I embedded code for users to share Youtube videos from my website's pages on Facebook a while back.

Everything worked until recently and I didn't even change the code.

In Facebook debugging tools with many of my pages it has started to process them with a parse error.

This is not a consistent error message.

If you need to see a few examples go to Facebook Debugging Tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and copy and paste the following URLs into it.

```
http://topcommercials.tv/ads/funny-commercial-1414.php
http://topcommercials.tv/ads/banned-commercial-1372.php
```

I did finally get the above links to share on Facebook after beating my head against the wall trying to force Facebook to cache it.

Here are links that do not work:

```
http://topcommercials.tv/ads/funny-commercial-1365.php
http://topcommercials.tv/ads/banned-commercial-1364.php
```

The code in the above URLs is no different then the working code from a few days ago.

Facebook does return a og:url error but that is not the problem.  I have gotten the videos to share with the error, and my website used to automatically generate content along with the error.

I used to not be required to do this. Someone could share the videos on Facebook without any problems

Another clue that might help solve this problem is that I sometimes get error messages in the comment boxes that display.

(Warning: http://topcommercials.tv/ads/banned-commercial-1364.php is unreachable.)

Comment: You've got a lot of errors in your HTML. The ones that are working, are probably working out of luck. Take a look at the W3C Validator. http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spoke with my web host. They said that Facebook is having difficulty establishing a stable connection to the IP of my servers due to its nameservers not being set properly. I am working on resolving this issue. I will get back to you all!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will pull from whatever data is listed in the og:url meta tag. On the first broken link, the og:url is listed as http://topcommercials.tv/wallposts/fbwallpost/ads-1364.html - which is a 404.

Fix the 404, and Facebook should find the right data!

Comment: I just spoke with my web host.  They said that Facebook is having difficulty establishing a stable connection to the IP of my servers due to its nameservers not being set properly. I am working on resolving this issue.  I will get back to you all!